# Проверить занятость клетки на карте в игре JavaScript

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Пишу первую игру на JavaScript. Каждая игровая клетка имеет свой ID. Сделал объект к названием

```
 var map = {};
```

Когда что-то на клетке с ID 10 например есть - добавляю элемент в объект map

```
 map[10] = 1;
```

После чего, после того как игрок хочет перейти на клетку с ID 10, идёт проверка

```
 if (map[10] === 1) {
 //Отмена передвижения
  }
```

Подскажите, правильно ли я делаю? Или есть способы лучше?

Comment: Для простенькой игры, для начала - сойдет. Позже у вас в каждой клетке будет набор свойств - проходимость, текстурка, объекты, и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

```
let map = {};
```

Для условий желательно использовать тип `bool`

```
map[10] = true;
```

Передвигать только если условие совпало (если `map[10]` не `true`, т.е. в данном случае неопределён)

```
if (!map[10]) {
  //передвижение
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а в целом, способ правильный?